# Excel vba - bug quando insere varias celulas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso montar uma tabela na qual serao inseridas informaçoes nas colunas A B e C, e a data e hora de quando foram modificadas serao inseridas na coluna D
 Criei um programa simples q grava o momento da mudança, mas quando insiro varias colunas de uma vez como demonstrado na imagem 1, o offset joga as modificaçoes para as colunas vizinhas, dependendo do tamanho do bloco de seleçao em q copio e colo. Preciso fazer com q as informaçoes se restrinjam a coluna D pois futuramente precisarei utilizar as coluas E F G para outras funçoes, e preciso q seja aceito inserir varias colunas ao mesmo tempo, pois preciso copiar e colar um grande numero de linhas para essa nova planilha. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá. Edite sua pergunta removendo o print com o código e escrevendo o mesmo como texto. Assim fica mais fácil do pessoal simular seu código e resolver seu problema

Answer (score 0):

Edie boa noite, segue o primeiro código, relativamente simples. Espero que atenda sua expectativa.

Essa primeira interpretação não leva em consideração uma inserção de coluna selecionando toda a coluna A. Já que fazendo isso ele preenche toda coluna D com a data do evento, faça o teste.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row <= 10 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Now()
        Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Isso nao muda minha situaçao pois isso escreveria por cima das colunas vizinhas e depois apagaria com "nada" sendo escrito por cima de novo. O problema é que futuramente essas colunas vizinhas serão preenchidas, e quando for necessario modificar as colunas A,B e C novamente, eu perderei as informaçoes.

Comment: Entendi vou escrever uma nova versão e posto aqui.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Acho q consegui algo parecido com o q eu queria
O "truque" esta no bloqueio e desbloqueio das celulas q serao modificadas, se eu desbloquear apenas a coluna D e manter as colunas E F e G bloqueadas, quando eu colar uma caixa de seleçao de varias celulas, conforme image 2, o offset tentará escrever uma caixa de varias celulas mas apenas conseguira preencher a coluna D
Isso nao é ideal pois vai gerar erro e uma caixa de alerta  ira aparecer, eu ainda nao encontrei um jeito de selecionar "fim" automaticamente. Alem disso eu gostaria de criar algo q nao rodasse dependendo de erros pois quero evitar corromper o codigo, ou gerar loopings.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, é melhor não usar o Offset já que o destino do `Now()` é fixo (coluna D). Repare no `If i <= 10`  antes do `Cells(i, 4).Value = Now()`, que é para não adicionar o resultado de `Now()` em tudo o que estiver selecionado a mais do que a linha 10, já que uma das suas condições é o `Target.Row <= 10`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_CHANGE(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowInicio As Long
    Dim numberOfRowSelected As Long

    rowInicio = Target.Row
    numberOfRowSelected = Selection.Rows.Count

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row <= 10 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For i = rowInicio To rowInicio + numberOfRowSelected - 1
            If i <= 10 Then Cells(i, 4).Value = Now()
        Next i
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```